# How to flow type an object map such that value must contain key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, flowtype

I'm trying to properly type (using Flow) a `createReducer` helper function for redux. I've used [the code from `redux-immutablejs`](https://github.com/indexiatech/redux-immutablejs/blob/b6fc5d700966020cce860488487ccfc9b002e7f0/src/utils/createReducer.js) as a starting point.

I'm trying to follow the [advice from the flow docs about typing redux reducers](https://flow.org/en/docs/react/redux/#toc-typing-redux-reducers), but wrap it in a helper function with the shorthand map style. The basic idea is:

Create a separate type for each action:

```
type FooAction = { type: "FOO", payload: boolean };
type BarAction = { type: "BAR", payload: string };

type Action = FooAction | BarAction;
```

Pass a js object map to `createReducer` to provide a reduction function for each action.

```
createReducer<Action>({}, {
  FOO: (state, action) => state,
  BAR: (state, action) => state,
})
```

What I'd like to see from the type system:

1. Within the reducer function, `action` is typed correctly (`FOO` sees `FooAction`), such that misuse of the `payload` generates an error.
2. Error if the map contains extra (invalid) keys
3. Error if the map is missing keys (for the defined types)

The part I think I can't quite figure out is, can I define a map type such that the key must contained by the value type?

```
type Action<T = string> = { type: T, payload: any };
type Reducer<S, A> = (state: S, action: A) => S;
type HandlerMap<S, T> = {
  [T]: Reducer<S, Action<T>>,
};
```

I don't think the above quite works, because the generic `T` would contain all of the type strings, as opposed to referring to a single one.

See this example on [try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiQrAcQKYDtMCcBLAY1AAtNoAHfUSAV2yIBcDZs1kmBPa0AQWatsAHgAqoALygAzk0LYA5gD5JoAN6hu1AFyhRAGlCUAhlzjGAJruPYuoAL4BuTj0ygASpgt0i+YQGVDPhUpAApZYyZMXUDQY0E2XT4ASkkVf2dELTcACRsLaHwAWWNKAMNREPVEUFAAbVEAXV1Pb188cv4EkUqlfUQnF14AUQAPOXimTyY6PGxRV1UxJVDQgRY2ZdSJFVFt3cz6Rg3sUCI8TEjMVp8-WL4k7uElFZrQAmwCFmNofyYrmL9WqkfKFPDSXR5bAFYqlToAEgACnhYNQ8NwFtRhHxDABybK4l79ZItLy3Dr3FRqN4XGZzUDhf5RGKqD5fAg-P5XQyTIRJfbVWq1EAyAgAW0o0AIkAIXneEsKYpwTKEb1qRDYsjIoJoUl5bFAADJDXFugA6bKgAD82uhYOkdX12AtrkaoF0DAsmBluAsmSF70gDIAhCC7fhUtSA7VabNThEos4A-ZkAHY-SwzC8IzuaaTskkw5nCmAxwRWNjAq3ABVaTGBSYDhoM4XK5xTSLSCwPCgS5EUh51WW9ZCPiqDTZXS4vi4wwmMywSy6WTyBRFrKLEdsABC447OlAuO3s6MpnMVlA2DoYoARjRBsPugBhPeTw9Pk-z8+6G+wWCFGx10fE4ABFX1cKcQNxItQBFbBYFPBdLCGNx1joH4t1OCQ1VAAAfLoTj4HD8Mw7diIIoQn3IzCQMLUtLS5KJxzeYwrWXOQPgUIFQBvNjL2vO88G4og+N-f9LmwfpBlLc5LiiG52gCJlMCCZh0OgTCVjUexDCjfhdBzKIeW6R5CIFPTalCJ0zS-RcLxXTiCxw9N42UwsdLebcDITFTB0SCid3MnCrPNWyl3428Izo0AXJkNy3g82oQO85TjJOUyhBAoKAzg2AmBkWY3CYEF8uKghpHeCrircQgFFIUrMFkQwbzofLpFIWA6GgCweLceDEPPMh8EbAMQpOGyzzs3RMAlbgnLTTA6Vcq53KkpyRXgTrutAKUAGsioQ6RMDcfAUSE0AxXK6RONtLNaG7ALsCfIA). I feel like it is pretty close, but I can't quite get rid of all the type errors. Any flow wizards that can show me how it's done?

Comment: Was asked offline to take a look at this, but will be busy for the next two days—commenting here so that you can ping me on Stack Overflow in case I haven’t gotten around to it by EOD 2019-06-08.

Comment: I'm playing around with it to see what can be accomplished, though I'll say that for our project we haven't bothered to fully type our redux system. We've found that typing the action creators/thunks and the reducer inputs are sufficient. (And this is coming from someone who loves flow and maintains the flow-typed repo -- just hasn't been worth the chaos to type the internals of redux.)

Comment: The starting point for this was an attempt to get rid of the "constants" pattern seen so often for redux action types, and instead just use strings with flow to catch problems. This quickly took me down a rabbit hole...

Answer (score 2):

While the problem exactly as specified has (I believe) no solution in
the current version of Flow, I can provide an approach that works if
you’re willing to provide Flow with a little more information upfront.

> The part I think I can't quite figure out is, can I define a map type
> such that the key must contained by the value type?

For tasks like these, [`$ObjMap`](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-objmap) is usually going to be the the
tool that you want to turn to. But `$ObjMap` only transforms existing
map types, and it only transforms their values (key-agnostically), so it
doesn’t quite suffice here. The trick is to give Flow a mapping from
action name to action type explicitly:

```js
type Actions /* helper type, never instantiated */ = {
  FOO: FooAction,
  BAR: BarAction,
};
type Action = $Values<Actions>; // = FooAction | BarAction;
```

I posit that this is not too objectionable, as you’re already defining
`type Action` in your example. Given that you can define `Action` in
terms of `Actions`, there’s not even much additional redundancy (modulo
the discussion below about relating keys to `type` attributes—read on).

Given such an action-map type, we can type `createReducer` as follows:

```js
type HandlerMap<O, S> = $Exact<$ObjMap<O, <A>(A) => (S, A) => S>>;
type Reducer<O, S> = (S, $Values<O>) => S;

declare var createReducer: <O, S>(
  initialState: S,
  handlers: HandlerMap<O, S>
) => Reducer<O, S>;
```

[Here is a usage example:](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQAXAngBwKagGK1gIIDGyAlrAHagC8oA3qGlgFygBEOA8p2wDSjoAhqjiCAJqwoBXALYAjTACdQAXwDcKDNgBCgxcTKUa9RltZttBAEp8Bw0RNABnZItIUA5qo2asoA+QUTqDAAFSgABaY0FjKTJj8FJgAbkqg7i6CFGSCyJhioKFgtHSIoLjcrHiEJIG8ZaCWVqy6+rWU9eq+2AFGtAAkAGqC0FKYTgA8vUEAfGohxbj406AAPo160z7xoAASWWLQSgCygugTnPwAyjPG-QCiAB6CJBP9nHIAVqfnl6BTMwAFAQAJQ0W6Aq78UHg0A3ObdUBWfJSIhKC7XW60SH8IYjMaTTgzMHUW5XHxiTBEaB6bDJPSgIiKTC5TDIsSopSsDFwoENdykHLQK7IVmsKENCIHI6KJysfYUQ4nM48m6IEm3dmcxSqhGIIiUFygZkctHKWhMll5LVmqbtIK45HiTgUaCoAiKRTCCYuNyeGZ88qAgDaAF1WP0nWIXW6PV7UD7XO4PMT6uVSuVylxOKxAZk8vwXoYKBrQMGAHSV-MJUBFwLloQiWDicvIWA4UiPfKAgAMINDaczTVz1cL9tLFarooLtftDfszbEA4a5RAuDg8FA8FI0GgoBggi8glMfiUilgylIkFAqFgUlAUgoBpkMkw2UYUX3sF3CGToGg7gJCuCyMrAMjoEceRboKEQftgUQxJAUh7q+ThOIe2BsOg56xGgoAAAaWAAWvh6TBDIpBoX+7jAWusBfFSyAntgchSExmCPJRyDBO4oD0Z8jH-oKSgjGw5a0cAxEjtONZ1pQpajg0Kjqj4kHGuMyHIBGUYxu6nrer6yZYmWoYaMyTiacYJraoC5mafwDDxOY2a2I2DisAAbKoIJmRp0BMbQ1lmrZfnIA5zHmE0rkLuI5hOJ2bDeRoa73C8sGwNeyCfpA34bn+AFJMEB4eMEx47GeF7pNej7Pq+2T5OJIB2f5VkosFzVhSYTnsC5-BuYucUJUliBNaFrWmkoIUWf54XdRY1jRU2sWgF5Kg+SNwAdeNNkdbNZjsMRi3uYwihjMNQA)

```js
type FooAction = { type: "FOO", payload: number };
type BarAction = { type: "BAR", payload: string };

type Actions /* helper type, never instantiated */ = {
  FOO: FooAction,
  BAR: BarAction,
};

const reducer = createReducer<Actions, $ReadOnlyArray<string>>(
  ([]: $ReadOnlyArray<string>),
  {
    FOO: (state, action) => [...state, action.payload.toFixed(0)],
    BAR: (state, action) => [...state, action.payload],
    // Flow will flag a type error if you uncomment the following line,
    // complete with the helpful message "property `BAZ` is missing in
    // object type but exists in object literal".
    //BAZ: (state, action) => state,
  }
);

let result: $ReadOnlyArray<string> = [];
result = reducer(result, { type: "FOO", payload: 6 });
result = reducer(result, { type: "BAR", payload: "six" });
// Each of the following lines flags a type error if uncommented.
//result = reducer(result, { type: "FOO", payload: "six" });
//result = reducer(result, { type: "BAR", payload: 6 });
//result = reducer(result, { type: "BAZ", payload: true });
```

Note that the keys of the `Actions` type do not have to be related in
any way to the `type` fields of the actions themselves. For instance, if
we instead used the action type definitions

```js
type FooAction = { type: "ONE", payload: number };
type BarAction = { type: "TWO", payload: string };

type Actions /* helper type, never instantiated */ = {
  FOO: FooAction,
  BAR: BarAction,
};
```

then the code would still typecheck successfully, but presumably would
fail at runtime (or, from a different perspective: it is not possible to
actually implement `createReducer` with the above types). But worry not,
for we can ask Flow to check this condition, too:

```js
// Check that each the `type` property of each value in the action-map
// corresponds to that action's key.
(function<K: $Keys<Actions>>(
  x: $PropertyType<$ElementType<Actions, K>, "type">
): K {
  return x;
});
```

The above will fail to typecheck if you accidentally define an action
that does not have a `type` property or whose `type` property does not
correspond to its key in the `Actions` type. The existence of that
function is a proof that the map is constructed correctly.*

Ideally, we would be able to require that this condition hold for any
action-map `O` that’s used with `createReducer`—we should be able to
write

```js
type HandlerMapCorrectnessProof<O> = <K: $Keys<O>>(
  $PropertyType<$ElementType<Actions, K>, "type">
) => K;

declare var createReducer: <O, S>(
  initialState: S,
  handlers: HandlerMap<O, S>,
  proof: HandlerMapCorrectnessProof<O>
) => Reducer<O, S>;
```

and simply require clients to pass `(x) => x` as a third argument to
`createReducer`. However, if we attempt to do so, we run into [Flow
issue #7548](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7548), so for now you’ll have to rely on extrinsic
verification that your action maps are consistent (either by manual
inspection or with individual static checks as discussed above).

All together, then, [here is a complete example that includes the static
check](https://flow.org/try/#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-iY-EEYU0P3g738OMJ0C+g2+bBWfJSIhKKPpv20JP8TXa56enHx6h+70+MSYIjQPTYXbKIhPXKYHNiPNKViF30E8ruUg5aDe5Dd1jJhqjCjOpROViOxcuiNDoU1v29-uKLc+e5BZCgJ59-PKWidiZ5PeXjlnLmgZE58ScCjQVAER7COEuNxPDxEdQHBABtABdFE3zED8vx-RQ-wA9wPGrepylKcpyi4ThWHBTI8n4X5KB3UAwJBCiCISE5YRBIQRFgcQQU+HBSEJfJwQABmFCD0Kwpo8KoojYVI8jKOnQiaLOOj7EYsReIacoehwOB4FAeBSGgaBQBgQQvEEUw-CUZZlFITZUFgKRQGhe4ZGZbJjkgWAtIQFDQGgdwEkUo1QFs9BGTydTx2mZAokiaJ0ChbTmScJw9OwNh0HJJQ1lmSwAC1FlIYIZGypw3PcbyelgMMm1PFU5CkU9MEJbLkGCI4StDMr3PHJQ9jYMEsKNDLBIk6jiIoUihIaFQRR8AKz2eKRoGQaCJlgz9v1-VB-1cFDizIiCNCeJwZtPWhz33cFdv2-gGHicwcNseiHFYAA2VQlUQU7ZuMI7LxO6bZvOwzMHMJobtk8RzHywk2CejQejpbZ1k2ULsCclyNM8VqkmCXSPGCAyVWMh50k2GzYDslk8jEMEQFeg6povJQvr2n6TEu9hrv4W65NBtiIcVKHgCp97c0+qnfuZixrCBhiQdAR6edufnDsFunhaZsx2AyiW7sYRQDkhxAgA).

A word of warning: The mechanism built in this answer relies heavily on
type-level manipulation that is decidedly more complicated than most
everyday Flow code. This has two important implications: (a) it is far
more likely to hit strange bugs in Flow (like #7548 above), and (b) it
may be hard to understand for collaborators who are not well versed in
Flow or not used to thinking about types in this way. Personally, I find
that I get the most out of Flow when I use a [very simple subset of it,
basically just disjoint unions of read-only exact objects](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/6549#issuecomment-464251383). I
present this post in response to being directly asked to answer this
question, but I would hesitate to put it into production myself. That
said, this is a topic on which reasonable people may reasonably differ
in opinion.

* This statement is not quite precise enough to be correct—what I
really mean is that the fact that the *identity function* has this type
is the proof claimed, or in other words that the relevant [identity
type](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/identity+type) is inhabited. Flow does not have the vocabulary to discuss proper
identity types, but its formulation of type bounds is strong enough that
I suspect that any function of this type that the current version of
Flow accepts must actually be the identity function.

Comment: wchargin thanks, there is a lot to digest here. Could you explain how `$ObjMap` works here? I read that documentation a dozen times, thought it should be useful, but failed to do anything useful with it. Also, you seem to have forgotten the "complete example" link... I agree that I may not want to actually include this in a project if this is the case. My hope was that it could be written generically and stuck in a library, but I see that the details are leaking into the usage. As I keep finding with flow, the easy things are easy and the hard things are very hard.

Comment: @murrayju: (Fixed link, thanks.) The quick explanation is: you can read `$ObjMap<O, <A>(A) => (S, A) => S>` as “the object type `O`, but modify the values as follows: for each value—call it `A`—replace it with the function type `(S, A) => S`”. So `{FOO: FooAction}` becomes `{FOO: (S, FooAction) => S}`. Please feel free to ask further questions; I can expand the answer according to which parts are unclear to you.

Comment: You may find it helpful to peruse <https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7090> for a somewhat simpler but structurally similar `$ObjMap` example.